# Build failure in playwright module in node js

Tags: node.js, npm, playwright

In Node JS, I use the playwright(I am using playwright-core 1.35.0) module, but the build fails with the below error,

```
{
            "moduleIdentifier": 
    "/myproject/node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/appIcon.png",
            "moduleName": "./node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/appIcon.png",
            "loc": "1:0",
            "message": "Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
    https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders\n(Source code omitted for this binary file)",
            "moduleId": 96042,
            "moduleTrace": [
                {
                    "originIdentifier": 
    "/myproject/node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/crApp.js",
                    "originName": "./node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/crApp.js",
                    "moduleIdentifier": 
    "/myproject/node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/appIcon.png",
                    "moduleName": "./node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/appIcon.png",
                    "dependencies": [
                        {
                            "loc": "30:51-83"
                        }
                    ],
                    "originId": 98916,
                    "moduleId": 96042
                },
                {
                    "originIdentifier": 
    "/myproject/node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/trace/viewer/traceViewer.js",
                    "originName": "./node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/trace/viewer/traceViewer.js",
                    "moduleIdentifier": 
    "/myproject/node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/crApp.js",
                    "moduleName": "./node_modules/playwright/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/chromium/crApp.js",
                    "dependencies": [
                        {
                            "loc": "13:13-44"
                        }
                    ],
                    "originId": 31499,
                    "moduleId": 98916
                }
}
```

Actual node js code

```
const { Core } = require('@adobe/aio-sdk');
const stateLib = require('@adobe/aio-lib-state');
const playwright = require('playwright');
.....
```

After deleting this module (/node_modules/playwright-core), I tried building the code, but it failed. Also tried with *npm install playwright-core@latest* but no luck. I am running this on a Mac. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: This also appears on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5627#issuecomment-955775403) . Someone suggests a solution there

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I dont have webpack config. Do you have any idea where to create this config?

Comment: See in https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/webpack